# Why is there no edit option below the question?

Tags: support, editing, suggested-edits, user-interface

This is not the first time but many times I've encountered this problem. There is no 'edit' option below the question as it usually is. Here's the screenshot:

[image]

What might be the reason for this?

Comment: From the [FAQ on Meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/81701/313042), probably the post has a pending suggested edit that has not been reviewed yet (see point no. 4).

Comment: was this during the recent [maintenance](https://stackstatus.net/post/625084791873781760/planned-maintenance-thursday-july-30-2020), when the site was read only?

Comment: @J.W. Tanner, no it was two days ago. However, the problem is solved now. Thanks for your concern.

Answer (score 7):

As @Brahadeesh notes, the question already had a pending suggested edit, which can be seen from the question's [timeline](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3773399/timeline):

[image]

You would have been able to see the pending edit if you [switch to the responsive mode](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/98846/295232) with the 'full site' link at the bottom of the page.

Comment: -@Glorfindel, but why the `edit` option is available on full site and not on mobile. I've screenshot of your answer on both modes [Mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcFge.png) and [full site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AlqN0.png)

Comment: @SarGe according to https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/161023/295232 this is by design. I don't really understand, but the mobile version of the site isn't actively maintained anymore.