# Bug in mobile version of the site.

Tags: support, bug, user-interface, mobile-web

Today, when I was going through the feeds, there was no option to go to the next page like it usually has. [image: e] However, earlier I was suggested to use full site version instead, where all features work properly. But it didn't work this time. Here's the screen shot of problem in [mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q02cN.png) and [full site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvFld.png) version.

What might be the potential issues? Also, referring to [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32278/why-is-there-no-edit-option-below-the-question#comment143955_32280) comment, why the mobile site is not looked after for improvement?

Comment: Your issue is not really an issue. Perhaps you are looking at the tab of interesting questions and there one usually does not have option of going to next page (it is a single page game I guess). At the end of page you see a link to browse complete list of questions and when you click on that you will get the page numbers and next and prev buttons to click.

Comment: It appears that this is afeature by design. The default page gives a list of questions in single page format perhaps not to intimidate a casual user that this site is full of an infinite number of questions.

Answer (score 3):

The option to go to the next page is the button with the triangle:

[image]

[Unlike the mobile apps](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/348075/295232), the mobile web version of the site is still supported, but Stack Exchange is in the middle of a multi-year program to switch to so-called [responsive design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/307862/295232) which is supposed to look good and work well on desktop, tablet and mobile phones alike. The Q&A pages have already been switched over, but e.g. the profile page has not yet. When that is done, it's expected that they will pull the plug for the mobile web version as well; the only advantage the mobile web version currently has is that it uses less bandwidth.

Comment: -@Glorfindel, I know about the triangle button but it was not displayed on either of the site modes.